apt does not show any packages available after adding ppa when there is a snap version of dosbox-staging
I am trying to install deb version of dosbox-staging.
I added the official PPA and ran apt update, but the only version offered was the snap version.
The PPA on Launchpad does show that there is a deb package for jammy, so I should be able to install it using APT.
how do I solve the deb package not being shown by APT?

You mention running apt update, but don't specify that the result was clean and output as expected.  What command did you execute that caused the snap version to be offered; as that detail may indicate that command is your error.

this is how I run apt update, sudo apt update && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update.

the way you run the command may deal with what I described as clean (ie. no warnings, errors) but doesn't address the output as expected, which includes no missing lines etc. You've also not provided the command used to install it; as there are few exceptions to an apt command trying to install an snap version as you indicate (examples being firefox and chromium with specific reasons as documented by Ubuntu devs which doesn't apply in your case). Depending on the (unrevealed) command the next step is apt policy enquiries, but you've not ruled out user-error yet
